# XCode & Clang do not recognize a class of mine despite proper include

Tags: c++, xcode, clang

Hey guys I have some class

```
//
//  renderGUI.h
//  raytracer
//
//  Created by Noah on 24/01/14.
//  Copyright (c) 2014 syx. All rights reserved.
//

#ifndef raytracer_renderGUI
#define raytracer_renderGUI

#include <SFML/Graphics.hpp>
#include <SFGUI/SFGUI.hpp>
#include <renderer.h>

class RenderGUI{

private:
    Renderer* renderer;
    std::shared_ptr<sfg::Window> window;
    std::shared_ptr<sfg::Button> render;
    std::shared_ptr<sfg::Button> abort;
    std::shared_ptr<sfg::ProgressBar> progress;
    std::shared_ptr<sfg::CheckButton> antialiasing;
    void OnComboSelect();
    void startRenderThread();
    void endRenderThread();
    unsigned int renderButtonEvent;

public:
    RenderGUI(Renderer* renderer);
    sfg::Window::Ptr getWindow();
    void update();
    void updateProgressBar(double progress);
    void renderScene();
};


#endif
```

and here is the renderer.h:

```
//
//  renderer.h
//  raytracer
//
//  Created by Noah on 31/01/14.
//  Copyright (c) 2014 syx. All rights reserved.
//

#ifndef raytracer_renderer
#define raytracer_renderer

#include <scene.h>
#include <thread>

class Renderer{

private:
    sf::Texture* texture;
    sf::Uint8* canvas;
    Vector resolution;

    Scene* scene;
    MaterialManager* materialManager;
    Camera* camera;

    bool canvasReady;
    bool antiAliasing;
    bool canRender;

    double progress;
    std::thread renderThread;

    Color traceRay (const Ray& ray, double, int iter) const;

    void setPixel(int x, int y, Color c);

public:
    Renderer(Scene *scene, MaterialManager *materialManager, Vector resolution, bool antiAliasing);

    sf::Texture* getTexture();
    sf::Uint8* readCanvas();
    double epsilon;
    void update();
    void render();
    void useAntiAliasing(bool antiAliasing);
    bool useAntiAliasing();
    bool isCanvasReady();
    void chooseCamera(Camera* camera);
    void startRenderThread();
    void endRenderThread();
    double getProgress() const;
};

#endif
```

But now my compiler tells me "Projects/ETH/ETH/raytracer/raytracer/renderGUI.h:19:5: Unknown type name 'Renderer'; did you mean 'sfg::Renderer'?" on line 19 and 31 even tho in my opinion it should find my class ...

Can anyone give me some hint?
Thanks in advance!

Peace

Comment: Circular include maybe? What does `scene.h` include?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without seeing your `scene.h` header file I'm guessing circular inclusion. The `renderGUI.h` header file includes the `render.h` header file which (probably indirectly) includes `renderGUI.h`.

In this case it's pretty simple to solve: Don't include `render.h` in `renderGUI.h`, only declare the `Renderer` class.

So the `renderGUI.h` file looks something like

```
#ifndef raytracer_renderGUI
#define raytracer_renderGUI

#include <SFML/Graphics.hpp>
#include <SFGUI/SFGUI.hpp>

class Renderer;

class RenderGUI{

private:
    Renderer* renderer;
    ...
};

#endif
```

The reason this work is because you only use a `Renderer` pointer in the definition of the `RenderGUI` class, so it's enough that the compiler knows that there is a class existing with the name `Renderer`, the compiler doesn't need to know more information about that class.

Of course, in the source file where you actually work with instances (or pointers to instances) of the `Renderer` class you need the full definition, so there you should include the header file.

Comment: Thanks a lot, works like a charm!
What I do not get is why this circular inclusion blocks me ... I mean I can include it in the renderer.cpp without troubles but the renderer.cpp contains the renderer.h as well so why doesn't it clash there as well?

Comment: The only question I have is: Who downvoted this and why?? (the +1 is from me)